# How to model data using Combine & SwiftUI

Tags: swift, model, swiftui, combine

I've been learning Swift & SwiftUI and all has been going well until very recently. I have successfully used `@Published` properties to keep my data & views in sync. However, I now want to  display some data that is a combination of several `@Published` properties.

The simplified data model class:

```
import Foundation

final class GameAPI: ObservableObject {

    struct PlayerStats: Identifiable, Codable {
        var gamesPlayed: Int
        var wins: Int
        var losses: Int
    }

    struct Player: Identifiable, Codable {
        var id = UUID()
        var name: String
        var stats: PlayerStats
    }

    struct Room: Identifiable, Codable {
        var id = UUID()
        var name: String
        var players: [Player]
    }

    struct ServerStats {
        var totalGamesPlayed: Int
        var totalPlayers: Int
        var totalPlayersOnline: Int
    }

    @Published var players: [Player] = []
    @Published var rooms: [Room] = []

    func addPlayer(name: String) {
        players.append(Player(
            name: name,
            stats: PlayerStats(
                gamesPlayed: 0,
                wins: 0,
                losses: 0
            )
        ))
    }

    func removePlayer(id: UUID) { ... }

    func updatePlayerStats(playerId: UUID, stats: PlayerStats) { ... }

    func getLeaderboard() -> [Player] {
        return players.sorted({ $0.stats.wins > $1.stats.wins }).prefix(10)
    }

    func getServerStats() -> ServerStats {
        return ServerStats(
            totalGamesPlayed: ...,
            totalPlayers: ...,
            totalPlayersOnline: ...,
        )
    }
}
```

View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LeaderboardTabView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var gameAPI: GameAPI

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("TOP PLAYERS")
            Leaderboard(model: gameAPI.getLeaderboard())
            // ^^^ How can I make the view automatically refresh when players are added/removed or any of the player stats change?
        }
    }
}
```

How can I wire up my views to leaderboard & server stats data so that the view refreshes whenever the data model changes?

Comment: Are there particular functions on `GameAPI` that you're seeing don't cause the view to refresh? Could you add the contents of `Leaderboard`? Just tried out your code with two buttons to add/remove players, and a simple `List` inside a `Leaderboard` view and the views are refreshed correctly.

Comment: @SebJachec I had written this example without trying and you are totally right, it works as expected. So there must be something wrong I did in my original code. Thank you!